# LaTeX on IBM AIX 5.3

Tags: installing, distributions

I want to use LaTeX on IBM AIX 5.3, has support for UNIX on IBM AIX 5.3 stopped? If so should I use an old version, say from 2009.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Binaries for `powerpc-aix` have been dropped from TeX Live 2013. I'm afraid you have to compile them yourself. The best place for asking about this is the [TeX Live mailing list](http://tug.org/mailman/listinfo/tex-live)

Comment: @egreg this looks like an answer for me. Or should we wait for him to post the answer what he gets from the mailing list?

Comment: Thanks, looks like I would have to compile the libraries myself. I will check with TeX Live mailing list.

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, support for the `powerpc-aix` platform has been dropped from TeX Live  with the 2013 release.

I don't have any TeX Live 2012 DVD available, but in the DVD with the 2011 release the binaries are present. However, upgrades to packages will not be available and you'll be stuck with what's on the DVD (which is better than nothing).

You may ask for information in the [TeX Live mailing list](http://tug.org/mailman/listinfo/tex-live); the kind people there will be happy to help and provide hints about how you can compile the binaries yourself (possibly not all of them will compile, for instance `xetex` that relies on several libraries that may not be available for the `powerpc-aix` platform).

Comment: Regarding 'upgrades to packages', do you mean only that one would need to update packages manually?

Comment: @jon Yes: the repositories only carry the most recent release, so a 2012 `tlmgr` will not be able to run updates; this is not a problem for many packages, but some have dependencies that strictly depend on available binaries (`biblatex` and `biber`, for instance). The "compile yourself" path is preferable, if possible.

Comment: `biblatex`/`biber` was exactly what I was thinking of (rather than, say, `enumitem`).  For some packages, the OP may be interested in [tex-archive/install/macros/latex/contrib](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/install/macros/latex/contrib), which contains many packages in the easily-installable `.tds.zip` format.